# Calculating Area of Irregular Curved Polygon in Python

Tags: python, area

I know the x, y coordinates of the blue dots shown in the image. How can I calculate the area of an irregular shape bounded by these points? Number of points on upper and lower surfaces are different

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVexj.png)

Comment: You can use the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula). Note that your points need to be sorted counterclockwise, as stated in the article.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Fractalism, You can use Schoelace formula.
Here is an implementation for python using Numpy. I took it from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula_for_polygonal_area#Python):

```py
import numpy as np
# x,y are arrays containing coordinates of the polygon vertices
x=np.array([3,5,12,9,5]) 
y=np.array([4,11,8,5,6]) 
i=np.arange(len(x))
#Area=np.sum(x[i-1]*y[i]-x[i]*y[i-1])*0.5 # signed area, positive if the vertex sequence is counterclockwise
Area=np.abs(np.sum(x[i-1]*y[i]-x[i]*y[i-1])*0.5) # one line of code for the shoelace formula
```